# Texture packs have no effect in Minecraft on Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux, ubuntu

I'm running Minecrat 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I can add .zip files to my `texturepack` and `resourcepack` folders, and they show up in-game in the texture pack menu. I can select them and turn them on. But they don't actually have any in-game effect- no textures change. Anyone have troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct folder structure? It changed a lot in the last 10 major updates. I don't know how well the wiki worked back then, but you can use the edit history there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a very simple answer; I was trying to apply a texture pack that was made for a newer version of minecraft than I'm running. Texture packs fitting that description (usually called "resource packs", a generalization of the "texture pack" that came *after* minecraft 1.3.1) appear in the lit of available texture packs in-game, but will not actually be applied.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not much of an expert with Ubuntu, in fact I havn't used it whatsoever, but I think I know your problem. Unzip the .zip files you put in there and replace the .zip folders with the unzipped ones. Hope this helps, please tell me if you still proceed to have problems or better if this works. Thanks :D